# Handling image from Google Maps APIs (staticmap)

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get an image from GoogleMaps APIs, more precisely from the staticmap API.
The problem is that in other APIs from GoogleMaps you can choose wether you want your info from the API in JSON or XML, but with staticmap (which returns an image) it seems you can't.
So I don't know how to handle the image provided by the URL since I don't know how it is coded.

This is what I´m trying to do:

```
import requests

url = ("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400path=weight:3%7Ccolor:orange%7Cenc:polyline_data")
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.json())
```

Given that the info is probably not in Json it raises the following error:

```
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Hope you've got any advice about how to turn the response into something usable.

Answer (score 2):

ummmm... ok, you are thinking too much.

> staticmap (which returns an image)

Yes, since you are right, so this is what you have put it `<img src="here"/>`:

Following is a demo of it. I used the example from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#EncodedPolylines).

```html
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:orange%7Cenc:_fisIp~u%7CU}%7Ca@pytA_~b@hhCyhS~hResU%7C%7Cx@oig@rwg@amUfbjA}f[roaAynd@%7CvXxiAt{ZwdUfbjAewYrqGchH~vXkqnAria@c_o@inc@k{g@i`]o%7CF}vXaj\h`]ovs@?yi_@rcAgtO%7Cj_AyaJren@nzQrst@zuYh`]v%7CGbldEuzd@%7C%7Cx@spD%7CtrAzwP%7Cd_@yiB~vXmlWhdPez\_{Km_`@~re@ew^rcAeu_@zhyByjPrst@ttGren@aeNhoFemKrvdAuvVidPwbVr~j@or@f_z@ftHr{ZlwBrvdAmtHrmT{rOt{Zz}E%7Cc%7C@o%7CLpn~AgfRpxqBfoVz_iAocAhrVjr@rh~@jzKhjp@``NrfQpcHrb^k%7CDh_z@nwB%7Ckb@a{R%7Cyh@uyZ%7CllByuZpzw@wbd@rh~@%7C%7CFhqs@teTztrAupHhyY}t]huf@e%7CFria@o}GfezAkdW%7C}[ocMt_Neq@ren@e~Ika@pgE%7Ci%7CAfiQ%7C`l@uoJrvdAgq@fppAsjGhg`@%7ChQpg{Ai_V%7C%7Cx@mkHhyYsdP%7CxeA~gF%7C}[mv`@t_NitSfjp@c}Mhg`@sbChyYq}e@rwg@atFff}@ghN~zKybk@fl}A}cPftcAite@tmT__Lha@u~DrfQi}MhkSqyWivIumCria@ciO_tHifm@fl}A{rc@fbjAqvg@rrqAcjCf%7Ci@mqJtb^s%7C@fbjA{wDfs`BmvEfqs@umWt_Nwn^pen@qiBr`xAcvMr{Zidg@dtjDkbM%7Cd_@"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the problem, this is the code:

```
import requests

url = ("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400path=weight:3%7Ccolor:orange%7Cenc:polyline_data")
r = requests.get(url)
image = r._content
with open("map.png","wb") as file:     #with this you create a usable file .png
    file.write(image)
```